# Phonegap > cordova-plugin-ble-central > Info on paired device?

Tags: ios, cordova, bluetooth

I'm looking for information on Phonegap Cordova if this plugin (https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central) can display the status of already paired devices?

Currently, I can see BT devices not paired (using the sample code - https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/tree/master/examples/battery) but I'm looking to output the status (i.e. connection strength, battery status and name of device) of a paired BT device.

Specifically Apple Pencil paired to an iPad Pro.

Comment: I've been able to do that using the Connect example from that same repo